# Changing the value of an NSString passed to a function

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, variables

I have a sound all set up and playing fine, but I want to change the sound depending on the value from an `NSString`. Here is my code:

```
- (void) playSound {
    CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
    CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
    soundFileURLRef =CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"glass", CFSTR ("wav"), NULL);
UInt32 soundID;
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
}
```

I would like `@"glass"` to be the value of a string coming from somewhere else, which is defined like this `NSString *sound = @"newSound";`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
- (void) playSound:(NSString *)soundFile {
    CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
    CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
    soundFileURLRef =CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) soundFile, CFSTR ("wav"), NULL);
    UInt32 soundID;
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
}
```

There are many different ways to do this.  You could even have the ".wav" be part of the soundFile string that is passed in, in case you want to have control over whether you open .wav or .mp3, etc.

Comment: Thanks I got this method working. Just have to remember to set the string up as follows: 
    NSString *soundFile = @"fileName";
and call it like this:
    [self playSound:(NSString *)soundFile];

Comment: No, you don't have to set it up that way.   You can just pass @"fileName" as the argument and that cast is completely unnecessary.

Comment: As @bbum says, you can call it like this:
`[self playSound:@"filename"];`
or: 
`NSString *soundFile = @"filename";
[self playSound:soundFile]; `
You could even have a picker that lets you pick from a number of sounds.  For example, if you have  directory of sounds, you can iterate through the directory, get all the names, pass the names to a UIPicker and then let the users select the sound...  Possibilities are endless.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just define the method like so?

```
- (void) playSound:(NSString *)soundName {
    CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
    CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
    soundFileURLRef =CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) soundName, CFSTR ("wav"), NULL);
UInt32 soundID;
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
}
```

and then call it to play different sounds like :-

[soundPlayer playSound:@"glass"];

[soundPlayer playSound:@"newSound"];

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way:

Add this to your header file:

```
typedef enum {
    GlassSound,
    NewSound,
} SoundEffect;
```

Add this into the implementation block

```
- (void)playSound:(SoundEffect)soundEffect {
    NSString *sound = nil;
    switch (soundEffect) {
        case Glass:
            sound = @"glass.wav";
            break;
        case newSound:
            sound = @"newSound.wav";
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    if (sound != nil) {
        CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
        CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
        soundFileURLRef =CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) sound, NULL);
        UInt32 soundID;
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
    }
}
```